# How to edit an instance of a Series using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

As the title suggests I am trying to use pandas to edit certain strings in a datafile. The goal is to edit the "Stop names" that has "ST-" in it.  An example of strings under the "Stop names" would something like "4 AV", "96 ST", "99 ST-LEXINGTON AV", "200 ST-DON AV". I want to edit it so that it the string is "99 ST-LEX" and "200 ST-DON". (For context, the actual data file is massive and has other attributes. 200+ unique station names)

What I have tried so far is to check if the entire series has "ST-" in it and if it does change the string to something else. However, I am unable to edit the string where I want to edit it.

Here is the code that I have used:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv(stations)

df2["Index"] = df2["Stop Name"].str.rfind("ST-")

df2.loc[df2["Index"] != -1, 'Stop Name'] = df2["Stop Name"].str.slice(start = 2)+"HELLA STREETS"
```

Currently I am able to find all Station Names that have "ST-" in it and add "HELLA STREETS" to the back

end of the string, BUT as I mentioned before i want to be able to shorten the string.

In order to try to edit it after "ST-" I tried changing the .loc statement to this :

```
df2.loc[df2["Index"] != -1, 'Stop Name'] = df2["Stop Name"].str.slice(stop = df2["Index"]+4)
```

which doesnt work because ("df2["Index"]+4) is a whole series and "stop" requires an int value

So the question I want to ask is, Is there a way to reference the original df2["Index"] value at the beginning of the .loc statement so I can use it as the "stop" value for slice?

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

```
labels = ["4 AV", "96 ST", "99 ST-LEXINGTON AV", "200 ST-DON AV"]

for L in range(len(labels)): #check each label within list of labels
  i = labels[L].find("ST-") #checks if label has "ST-"
  if i != -1: labels[L] = labels[L][0:i+6] #removes the rest of the label
```

Hope this helps.